# WPF Parameters through Unity Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm instantiating a `View` throught the `Unity`, and this `View` has a `ViewModel` as parameter. However, this `ViewModel` has three other parameters, which two of them are already configureted on Unity, and the last parameter I need to get from the `MainView` that open the `SecondView`. (Crazy, hm?)

This method is called from my MainView (first view) when a button is clicked:

```
private void ShowAddVersionViewExecute()
{
    Window view = UnityServiceConfigurator.Instance.GetUnityContainer().Resolve<AddVersionView>() as Window;
    view.ShowDialog();
}
```

This is my AddVersionView (second view), which has its ViewModel as parameter.

```
public partial class AddVersionView
{
    public AddVersionView(AddVersionViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //InicializeComponents and set the viewModel to DataContext.
    }
}
```

This is the AddVersionViewModel's constructor

```
public AddVersionViewModel(IDialogService dialog, AbstractRepository repository, string versionNumber)
{
    //Some code here.
}
```

The `IDialogService` and `AbstractRepository` are resolved by `Unity`. **BUT** I want receive the `"versionNumber"` from the MainView.

1. How/What am I supposed to do it?
2. Is there any other way to perform that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter overrides to supply parameters at resolve time. There are several examples available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660920(v=pandp.20).aspx.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with `ParameterOverride` and it worked as I wanted.